# Postgres Insert Timestamp Loses Time Portion

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have done the research and haven't found any solution to the following issue.
I wrote a small utility to move data from SQLServer to Postgres using .NET Core and EF Core. Everything works fine except after data transfer Postgres timestamp loses time portion. Source class field as well as destination defined as DateTime. Context dataset  before update indicates date correctly - that is including time like so: `'{8/8/2018 6:04:15 AM}'`. But when I call `SaveChanges()` and review data in target Postgres DB - date shows up without time portion: `"2018-08-08 00:00:00"`.
This happens with TZ or without. Inserting the data using query, results in correct timestamp. So, it looks like the problem with Npgsql.EntityCore.PostgreSQL adapter to me...

So, has anyone encountered any similar issue? Any ideas, tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would look for a problem with data type you're passing and the conversion that is happening. You probably need to pass a different data type, but I'm not familiar with .NET EF

Comment: Thanks @Kamil, I'm looking into it, but no luck yet.